# Sign a document in embedded mode and send an email to the second receipt

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to build a POC for our internal application using DocuSign, but I have some issues.

The flow is:

create a template in docuSign with a set of dynamic fields to be populated from the client app
the template has 2 recipients that have to sign the document - client and buyer with empty emails. The emails should be populated dynamically based on the order, so they're not fixed
from the client app, create an envelope that will use the template, will populate automatically the fields from the template and will open an embedded page where the first user(client) can sign the document immediately(without going to mail)
immediately after the client finished signing the document, an email should be sent to the second recipient(buyer) to finish the signing

For now, I succeed to implement all the steps, except the last one - the document is not sent automatically to the second recipient for signing.

How can I do that?

I know that I can use a recipients lists for sending email to receipts, but this is not possible when using a template - I get an error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your template definition has the two recipient roles defined with different **Signing order** values.

The first recipient will have signing order 1, second signing order 2.

When you create the envelope from the template, you set the **clientUserId** for just the first signer. That way the second signer is a regular ("remote") email recipient.

If you'd like more help, please EDIT your question to show the code you use for creating the envelope from the template.